# Create catalog structure from excel file

Tags: java, excel

I'm currently trying to create a simple catalog structure using Java and reading values from an Excel file.

The problem is I don't know what would be the best approach to do this. So far I've read the properties from the Excel file via Apache POI and now I'm trying to represent them in Java via some sort of data structure. Simple example.

I have a Category class

```
   public class Category{
   String code;
   List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
   }
```

but the problem comes from the structure of the Excel which is the following (for simplicity I'll use letters)

```
[A] [B]
[A] [B] [C]
[A] [B] [C] [D]
[A] [B] [C] [D1]
```

Initially the idea was to create object A, assign object B to it, but when I go to the next row I'll have to search if A exists, then if B exists, and then assign C, and the deeper it goes, the more iterations would be necessary, so this won't be good performance wise..

Any ideas what would be the best approach to turn this into Categories objects in java? Maybe recursion would help here but I'm really out of ideas.

Comment: I must admit, i am a little confused on your requirement. Excel is nothing more than rows and columns. What do you mean "Category" , is that a cell on a row

Comment: well in each cell of the Excel have an id, which should be represented as a category object in java, so basically if the row has two cells -> cell1 and cell2, the id of cell2 would be subcategory of the id of cell1.

Comment: can you explain in brief about your catalog structure, what you achieve from it, i guess you want a design with a product - variant  concept or something else

Comment: Is this similar to directory structure mechanism. If `dirA` is not present, create it, then if `dirB` is not present under `dirA`, create `dirB`. Similarly, if `dirD` is not present under `dirC`, create `dirD`. But for `dirD1`, `dirC` is present. So just add `dirD1` under `dirC`. Is it so ?